# Is this audit clear enough?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I was reviewing LQP, and I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27852859). I asked in SOCVR, and was told that the user who posted that was spamming low quality content, and therefore all their answers were deleted as spam. They also [plagiarized](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51160403).

However, I don't think this is a good audit, as all the links lead to microsoft docs, and the code itself doesn't seem to be wrong or misleading. It requires extra knowledge to review correctly.

It also requires some knowledge of the topic at hand to realise that the links aren't directly related to the answer at all.

Is this a bad audit, and if so, can it be removed?

---

After a small discussion in the comments, I have learnt to click "Looks ok" only when I am familiar with the topic of the answer, or when I am 100 percent sure only. I have learnt my lesson to also use skip more than I do already.

The audit has been removed by a mod.

Comment: Imho it is not a bad audit, because this answer doesn't "look ok". The posted links have nothing to do with the question or the answer, these are unrelated noise.

Comment: if a post requires topic knowledge for a reliable "Looks OK" (which is almost always the case) then correct course of action for a reviewer lacking such knowledge is to [skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601). This is exactly how Looks-OK differs from recommending deletion because the latter typically doesn't require topic knowledge at all (for most kinds of non-answers it wouldn't even require reading the question - one doesn't need to look anywhere else at the post like "I'm having this problem too")

Comment: @gnat but it requires extra knowledge. Plus to review, one doesn't need to be an SME. The reason that answer was spam was because the user was spamming their answers everywhere.

Comment: That's exactly gnat's point. To recommend deletion you often do not need to know enough of the post's subject matter. But to recommend the post _not_ be deleted, many times you do require that knowledge. It's exactly the same as with close/reopen. It's much easier to know a post deserves closure even if you are not an expert on the tag, but to judge if a question should be reopen, you often need at least a modicum of expertise.

Comment: The take away is: click "Looks OK" when you **know** the post looks OK, not when it simply hits the right metrics superficially. (It's the same to recommend deletion, only it's much easier to make the determination).

Comment: @yivi I should have just skipped the review. I spent 2 minutes trying to make sense of the answer, when I could have skipped.

Comment: yes, Looks OK often requires extra knowledge. And it _always_ requires extra effort. Most basic check for Looks OK (in normal reviews, not audits) is to go to the question and make sure that post isn't copied from some prior answer, which is quite a popular trick among folks seeding voting rings. Incidentally (or not so incidentally), doing this necessary check would also reveal audits

Comment: **I really don't understand why people are so eager to click Looks OK without doing necessary checks**

Comment: @gnat Neccessary checks? I clicked all the links, what else to do? I studied the code to check if it's malware, what else?

Comment: you didn't click the most important link that is absolutely necessary for Looks OK - link to the question: "Most basic check for Looks OK (in normal reviews, not audits) is to go to the question and make sure that post isn't copied from some prior answer, which is quite a popular trick among folks seeding voting rings."